# MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter Java Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

is it possible to have two bean configuration for MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter in the same spring boot application?

I am working in company where the default configuration is to remove the null values from the dto properties, but my application need the null value in the dto in some api and other api I need the default configuration.

**Default configuration:**

```java
@Configuration
public class objectMapperConfig {

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public ObjectMapper defaultObjectMapperConfig() {
        objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL);
        objectMapper.setDefaultPropertyInclusion(JsonInclude.Value.construct(Include.NON_EMPTY,
                Include.NON_EMPTY));
        return objectMapper;
    }
}
```

**Second object mapper:**

```java
@Configuration
public class ReportObjectMapperConfig {

    @Bean("customObjectMapper")
    public ObjectMapper customObjectMapper() {
        objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.USE_DEFAULTS);
        objectMapper.setDefaultPropertyInclusion(JsonInclude.Value.construct(Include.USE_DEFAULTS,
                Include.USE_DEFAULTS));
        return objectMapper;
    }
}
```

I am trying to write my configuration like this

```java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter;

@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfig {

    private ObjectMapper defaultObjectMapper;
    private ObjectMapper customObjectMapper;

    public WebMvcConfig(ObjectMapper defaultObjectMapper,
            @Qualifier("customObjectMapper") ObjectMapper customObjectMapper) {
        this.defaultObjectMapper = defaultObjectMapper;
        this.customObjectMapper = customObjectMapper;
    }

    @Bean("defaultHttpMessageConverter")
    public MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter defaultMappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter() {
        MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
        converter.setObjectMapper(defaultObjectMapper);
        return converter;
    }

    @Bean("customHttpMessageConverter")
    public MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter customMappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter() {
        MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
        converter.setObjectMapper(customObjectMapper);
        return converter;
    }
}
```

any insight if I am doing something wrong or I missed something?

Answer (score 2):

Are the responses implemented with different classes? I would suggest using a single `ObjectMapper` but with the [`@JsonInclude`](https://javadoc.io/static/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations/2.16.1/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonInclude.html) annotation on DTOs or fields that have to be present when null.

UPDATE #1

The `maven-jaxb2-plugin` is based on `xjc` and that allows you to modify the generated source files. For your application, it looks like the [`annotate`](https://github.com/highsource/jaxb-tools/wiki/JAXB-Annotate-Home) plugin would do the job for your.

Comment: The default configuration has been used becuse we have 
java classes genrated from xsd files

Comment: @mohammedrabee How are you generating the classes from the XSD? What tools?

Comment: I am using maven-jaxb2-plugin plugin

Comment: @mohammedrabee You can use this: https://github.com/highsource/jaxb-tools/wiki/JAXB-Annotate-Home. I updated the answer.

Comment: will try that for differnet usecase

Answer (score 0):

@wilx
I soleved the problem by defining the type for each MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter:

```
    @Bean
public MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter defaultMappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter() {
    List<MediaType> supportedMediaTypes = new ArrayList<>();
    supportedMediaTypes.add(new MediaType("application", "json"));
    MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();

    converter.setObjectMapper(defaultObjectMapper);
    converter.setSupportedMediaTypes(supportedMediaTypes);
    return converter;
}

@Bean
public MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter customMappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter() {
    List<MediaType> supportedMediaTypes = new ArrayList<>();
    supportedMediaTypes.add(new MediaType("application", "custom+json"));
    MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();

    converter.setObjectMapper(customObjectMapper);
    converter.setSupportedMediaTypes(supportedMediaTypes);
    return converter;
}
```

after that whenver I want to use the customMappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter
I add the following to my api

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test", produces = "application/custom+json")
```